# Method in SSIS to transform flat file data (based upon scalar sql functions)

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Initially, I put together a TSQL script to bulk import data from a set of flat files. (see below).  Using functions in SQLSERVER it was easy to convert the data to the datatypes I want and to handle transforming the data based upon whatever unique conditions I might encounter with the data set.  For example, all columns could have spaces at the beginning or end, the date columns that represent null values are of a specific value, the data that is money can have a dash at the end of the number representing a negative number, etc.  So I use the scalar-valued functions in sqlserver to handle the various conditions and case statements to allow a consistent data set.

My goal now is to migrate this to SSIS, but it seems extremely cumbersome to replicate what I have already done within SSIS.  While SSIS does have tools to do the transforms (like the character map, data conversion, derived column tools, and script component).  -- it seems a massive amount of work to get what I already had in my script. It doesn't appear that I can re-use anything.  While that might be OK for a small table, keying in the same complex tranformations for 50+ columns per table is really going to be a chore -- and then to maintain that if I need to modify something?  uggh.  I must be missing something.  Thanks for your help.

```
            INSERT INTO [TEST1].[dbo].[Table1] 
            SELECT 
               dbo.TRIM([ID]) 
              ,dbo.FixDate([CompleteDate]) 
              ,dbo.TRIM([IsDeleted]) 
              ,dbo.Text2Numeric([QtyTotal]) 
              ,dbo.Text2Numeric([OrderQty]) 
              ,dbo.Text2Money([Price]) 
              FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK  '\\server1test\temp\import1.txt', FIRSTROW=2,
              FORMATFILE='\\server1test\temp\import1.Xml'
              ) as t1 ;
        GO
```

Comment: Without seeing what you've done for your UDFs, I don't think anyone would be able to say with any substance what your final solution would look like within SSIS. You are most likely looking at recoding your TSQL logic into the appropriate construct in SSIS. Based on the apparent complexity, I'd look at script component. If re-use is a crucial decision point, I would look at encapsulating your logic into a signed DLL and deploying that into the ETL server's GAC and referencing that from within a script task. SSIS should give you more traceability for skunky data over openrowset.

Comment: I could post the functions, but I'm not looking for help with my specific functions, but on how to handle this general problem.  Doing the transform as described above using a function is so easy -- and if I need to change something I just change the function and it applies to everything that uses it.  I don't see an equivalent in ssis and I am hoping I am wrong.

Comment: The script component did seem like the best way to go -- but there again; I would need to apply that component to many different transforms; basically the same transform or set of transforms to lots of different tables.  And there again; the maintainability of that seems a bit fragile.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not adequately understanding the problem. The maintainability of a TSQL function vs referencing a method in an external DLL would be approximate. The script component usage would look much like the TSQL `Row.CompleteDate = MyLibary.FixDate(Row.CompleteDate);` If you find a new scenario that FixDate has to address, it's a simple change to the method body in the DLL, no changes required to the package. Perhaps to make it more maintainable, you'd be interested in taking the basic GAC'ed DLL and creating your own custom component out of it. Would simplify usage across mux packages.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am somewhat new to SSIS, but I think the problem I am trying to address wouldn't be that uncommon. I am hoping to find a pattern or method for handling what I think would be a fairly common requirement. Your DLL solution is probably ideal, but 1) I don't really know how to do what you are suggesting with the DLL and GAC and 2) having to recompile and deploy a dll to the GAC as I iteratively work through my solution seems less than ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution that doesn't involve custom dll's and the GAC would be to just use an Execute SQL Task. I tried this and it works, but am wondering what the downside is. Another thought was to use the Ole DB Command and wrap this up in a stored procedure call. What would be the downside of that approach?